# Expected Unqualified-id before 'case'

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax-error

I get the error when I declare the array. Why does this happen and how do I fix it? I can't seem to declare the array without throwing this error. I tried using vector<> previously before this. I'm looking to create an array of strings. I've searched this error on google and for almost everyone I saw, it was a syntax error by switching around the code i.e "[]array" instead of "array[]". Here, I've put the array syntax in the correct order, but I still get this error. Thanks

```
int main()
{
    const string case[3]; //<- Error right here before 'case'
    int selection; //choice to open skin
    srand( time(0));
    int skinChance; //The number that determines the skin quality
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Open Case \n";
        cin >> selection;
        if(selection == 1)
        {
            skinChance = rand()%10;
            if (skinChance <= 5)
            {
                //Blue Skin
            } 
            else if (skinChance >= 6 && skinChance <= 9)
            {
                //Purple/Pink Skin
            }
            else if (skinChance == 10)
            {
                //Red Skin
            }

        } 
        else
        {
            cout << "Not valid\n";
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: If some of the answers solved your problem, mark it as accepted, instead of editing your title. SO is different and not a forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` is a protected keyword in C++, as it is neccessary for the switch-case statements. You can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `case` as a variable name. `case` is a keyword of `C++`. Since they are used by the language, these keywords are not available for re-definition or overloading.

You can see here the [list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) of all keywords used in c++.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

case is a keyword as per C/C++ standard.

```
switch(arg){
   case arg1:
   //some statements
   break;
}
```